# How to ignore error in JDBC's executeBatch function

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, batch-processing

I want to insert some data into RDBMS(MYSQL5.7, JDBC5.1), and I am using executeBatch to speed up. I found that when one insert sql of a batch of statement cannot execute properly, the remain will be ignored. I have to say that not what I expectd. I want to let RDBMS just **ignore** my error sql and continue execution.

Can anyone tell me what should I do or show me the right documentation url.
And I am glad for your help!

*And I know that "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ... " can help ignore DUPLICATE KEY error , but I want one more general solution.*

[MySQL JDBC DOC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-config-failover.html)

```
Connection connection = getConn();
Statement statemenet = connection.createStatement();
for (SearchUserItem user: result.getItems()) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(SOME_VALUES)";
}
int[] re = statemenet.executeBatch();
ananlyseBatchResult(re);
statemenet.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: According to the [documentation for `executeBatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--), this behavior must be implemented by both the driver and DBMS, and can't be toggled.

Comment: @4castle Thanks for your answer. I know what you mean, and I am not familiar with MySQL so I cannot find how to configure it properly to meet my request. Can you show me the right way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867059/executebatch-behaviour-in-case-of-partial-failure?rq=1